# Android libgdx does not recognize Facebook ShareDialog (Facebook SDK)

Tags: android, facebook, libgdx

I have a problem in integration Facebook Sharedialog with my android libgdx game:

1. In build.gradle (Project), I added `mavenCentral()` in the `buildscript { repositories {}}` section.
2. In build.gradle (Module: android) I added `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:7.1.0'` and `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-common:7.1.0'` in dependencies.
3. But in my MyGdxGame when I declared `ShareDialog`, it came with following error:

   > Cannot resolve symbol ShareDialog, Add library 'Gradle:com.facebook.amdroid:facebook-common:7.1.0@aar' to classpath.

   Even it did not recognize the `import com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog`.

I've tried the same with a normal Android app that is not Libgdx game and seen Facebook ShareDialog worked well.

Could you please advise if I did anything wrong?

I also tried with another library: gdx-facebook (https://github.com/TomGrill/gdx-facebook) but failed because the method `publish_actions` was deprecated. The detail can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/07/31/platform-update-publish-permission/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared your dependency in the android module, but `MyGdxGame` is in your core module - that's the problem here. You need to follow the documentation for working with platform dependant code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually I tried to declare the dependency in both Android and Core module but it didn't work. Actually I tried with another platform also: com.codeandweb.physicseditor and there was no problem.

Comment: Follow this guide https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code